# Порты в docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

У меня есть компоуз

```
version: '3'
services:
    mongo:
        image: "mongo:4.0.2"
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
    grader-v2-storage:
        environment:
          - VAULT_ENV=LOCAL
        volumes:
          - .envs/local.env:/app/.deploy/.envs/local.env
        build:
          context: ..
          dockerfile: .deploy/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
          - mongo
        network_mode: host
```

Докерфайл выглядит так:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS BUILD

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install make python3.7 python3-pip git
RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV PIP_CONFIG_FILE /app/.deploy/.secrets/pip.conf
ENV VAULT_ENV ${VAULT_ENV}

RUN PIP=pip PYTHON=python3.7 make deps
CMD PIP=pip PYTHON=python3.7 VAULT_ENV=${VAULT_ENV} make run
```

Если я НЕ памплю порты в монге, то она не видна (вроде очевидно). Но если я не маплю порты в сервисе, который собирается из докера, то он виден из вне, с хостовой машины. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В отличие от `grader-v2-storage`, в `mongo` не используется `network_mode: host`. Это означает, что в случае с `grader-v2-storage` докер использует одну сеть с основной (хостовой) машиной. Следовательно, все порты автоматически совпадают с хостовыми.

В случае, с `mongo` докер **НЕ** использует одну сеть с основной (хостовой) машиной. Следовательно, все порты **НЕ** совпадают с хостовыми и их нужно прокидывать руками